# How do I display values of an JSON object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsp

Here is what I got so far. Please read the comment in the code. It contains my questions.

```
var customer;   //global variable
function getCustomerOption(ddId){
      $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/WebApps/DDListJASON?dd="+ddId, function(opts) {
           $('>option', dd).remove(); // Remove all the previous option of the drop down
           if(opts){  
                customer = jQuery.parseJSON(opts); //Attempt to parse the JSON Object.
           }
      });
}

function getFacilityOption(){
      //How do I display the value of "customer" here. If I use alert(customer), I got null
}
```

Here is what my json object should look like: `{"3":"Stanley Furniture","2":"Shaw","1":"First Quality"}`. What I ultimately want is that, if I pass in key `3`, I want to get `Stanley Furniture` back, and if I pass in `Stanley Furniture`, I got a `3` back. Since `3` is the customerId and `Stanley Furniture` is  customerName in my database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the servlet *already* returns JSON (as the URL seem to suggest), you don't need to parse it in jQuery's `$.getJSON()` function, but just **handle** it as JSON. Get rid of that `jQuery.parseJSON()`. It would make things potentially more worse. The `getFacilityOption()` function should be used as callback function of `$.getJSON()` or you need to write its logic in the `function(opts)` (which is actually the current callback function).

A JSON string of

```
{"3":"Stanley Furniture","2":"Shaw","1":"First Quality"}
```

...would return "Stanley Furniture" when accessed as follows

```
var json = {"3":"Stanley Furniture","2":"Shaw","1":"First Quality"};
alert(json['3']);
// or
var key = '3';
alert(json[key]);
```

To learn more about JSON, I strongly recommend to go through [this article](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_JSON_(_JavaScript_Object_Notation_)). To learn more about `$.getJSON`, check [its documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

Comment: What? JSON is a string representation of JavaScript objects, so it *does* need parsing if you want to access it as a regular object...

Comment: Srry that it took a while to return back to you. I just want to make sure that I read the article that you sent me completely, plus school is pretty crazy around midterm time. However, I after reading it, I think I solve my problem. Thank you very. :)

Answer (score 2):

`getJSON` will fire an asynchronous XHR request. Since it's asynchronous there is no telling when it will complete, and that's why you pass a callback to `getJSON` -- so that jQuery can let you know when it's done. So, the variable `customer` is only assigned once the request has completed, and not a moment before.

`parseJSON` returns a JavaScript object:

```
var parsed = jQuery.parseJSON('{"foo":"bar"}');
alert(parsed.foo); // => alerts "bar"
```

.. but, as BalusC has said, you don't need to parse anything since jQuery does that for you and then passes the resulting JS object to your callback function.

Answer (score 2):

```
var customer;   //global variable
function getCustomerOption(ddId){
      $.getJSON("http://localhost:8080/WebApps/DDListJASON?dd="+ddId, function(opts) {
           $('>option', dd).remove(); // Remove all the previous option of the drop down
           if(opts){  
                customer = opts; //Attempt to parse the JSON Object.
           }
      });
}

function getFacilityOption(){
  for(key in costumer)
  {
    alert(key + ':' + costumer[key]);   
  }
}
```

Comment: I dont think your code work. Sorry. it return [object Object]. :( :(

Comment: Sorry for that... Try now with for() loop