# how to manipulate Json response like an object?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

my jQuery.ajax return JSon object. I firstly read other articles. but their response text not likes mine. 
**My Response content**: from firebug response

```
{"item":"[{\"country\":\"USA\",\"lan\":\"EN\"},{\"country\":\"Turkiye\",\"lan\":\"TR\"}]"}
```

Now i trying to alert countryName:

```
$('#loadData').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "WS/myWS.asmx/getDaa",
                data: "{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(msg) {
                $("#jsonResponse").html(msg);
                    $.each(msg.item, function(i, d) {
                        alert(this.country);
                        debugger;
                    });
                },
            });
        });
```

but it is alerting *"undefined"*

Comment: have you tried to just print a single value? Like alert(msg.lang) ? It works? And, why is your json data escaped? Also, instead of $.each() use   for(key in msg) {  alert(key + ':' + msg[key]); }
Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2373524/how-do-i-display-values-of-an-json-object/2373648#2373648

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The value of item is a string. Thus you first need to parse it as json. Try this.

```
$("#jsonResponse").html(msg);
    var item = jQuery.parseJSON(msg.item)
    $.each(item, function(i, d) {
        alert(this.country);
        debugger;
    });
},
```

Comment: Note that your jquery call expects a JSON response (dataType: "json"), jquery parses it for you. The correct solution is *not* to parse it again using parseJSON (even if it works in this case), but to output the correct JSON in your script "WS/myWS.asmx/getDaa"

Comment: @David-V: ok. I am analyzing this problem. i used JSonSerializer() method in C# and get result like this.

Answer (score 7):

```
{"item":"[{\"country\":\"USA\",\"lan\":\"EN\"},{\"country\":\"Turkiye\",\"lan\":\"TR\"}]"}
        ^
        |
        +---- It's a string, not an array !
```

Your JSON should look like

```
{"item":[ {"country":"USA","lan":"EN"},{"country":"Turkiye","lan":"TR"}]}
```

Then you can access it like

```
country = msg.item[0];
lang    = country.lan;

for (i=0; i< item.length; i++) { alert ( item[i].country); }
```

etc...

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that `msg.item` is a string.

The reason that it is a string is that initial double quote you have after `item:`. This also explains why your double quotes are escaped. You have:

```
{"item":"[{\"country\":\"USA\",\"lan\":\"EN\"},{\"country\":\"Turkiye\",\"lan\":\"TR\"}]"}
```

When you should have:

```
{"item":[{"country":"USA","lan":"EN"},{"country":"Turkiye","lan":"TR"}]"}
```